# unexpected trash contents

Tags: macos, trash

As I was proceeding to empty the trash on this machine (Mac OS X version 10.6.3), a listing of thousands of items began accumulating.  Trash itself shows some 237 items, many of them folders labeled as, for example "com.apple.AddressBook".  I am certain that I did not send the bulk of these items to trash.  Is it possible that one of the periodic Software Updates has eliminated files by sending them to Trash?  Or have I picked up some malware which has sent important stuff to trash?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Trash incorporates trashes from *all* the volumes, including the removable ones.

Chances are you had a pen drive or an usb disk connected.

Answer (score 0):

Updates from cupertino will not move files into the trash can.

`Option Click` one of the Mysterious files in your trash can and Click `Get Info` you should see an created date of `--` and a modified date of the time it entered the Trash-can folder.

Make sure that time stamp wasn't around a time you were checked the status of your winning  `Nigerian Lotto ticket`.